# Using docker-compose in azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I got my mean stack code working in a docker-compose configuration. If I run `docker-compose up` on my pc, then I can login to my app successfully on `localhost` If go to app service and click on docker-compose preview option and upload my docker-compose.yml file. After deploying it, when I click on the URL for the app I get application error and I'm not sure why. Perhaps I have to change something in my files to make it work in different environment? I appreciate any help with this!

I read somewhere that I don't have to provide username,password, or url details if using ACR in same subscription, which it is. So if that's the case, then authentication isn't the issue.

The frontend docker image and backend docker image are located in the azure container registry. I'm pointing to the registry when I setup docker in app service
The docker logs from azure say

```
2020-02-19 15:08:20.257 INFO  - Starting multi-container app, configuration = 


2020-02-19 15:08:22.806 ERROR - Pull image threw Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2020-02-19 15:08:22.806 ERROR - Pulling docker image  failed:
2020-02-19 15:08:22.806 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-02-19 15:08:22.806 ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2020-02-19 15:08:22.831 INFO  - Container logs from testinggc_backend_0_250edca0 = 
2020-02-19 15:08:28.902 INFO  - Stoping site testinggc because it failed during startup.
2020-02-19 15:08:30.129 INFO  - Starting multi-container app, configuration =
```

frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node

MAINTAINER Phil

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

backend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.16.3

MAINTAINER Phil

WORKDIR /src

COPY . /src

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
            - "4200:80"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this issue, the problem is the property `build` of the docker-compose that does not support in Azure App Service. You can get more details about the support options in [Docker Compose options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options).

So the solution for you is to create the image locally yourself and then push them to a docker registry, for example, the Azure Container Registry. Finally, you need to change the `build` into `image`. Then deploy it to Azure App Service and it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed from ```build``` to ```image```, but now I get an authentication error, which I don't understand because I'm pointing to the registry after choosing docker-compose option in app service. Error: https://pastebin.com/NmVwCRRV

Comment: @user6680 When you create the image and push them to the registry, I don't know which registry you use, but if the registry is not public, then you need to add the credential as environment variables for the registry. See the variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#ACRSettings).

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be to use the [more recent](https://www.docker.com/blog/open-source-cloud-compose/) (Oct. 2020) [`compose-cli`](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli), which is made to run both locally, and in the context of a [Microsoft ACI (Azure Container Instance)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/).

Example: "[Deploying a Minecraft Docker Server to the cloud](https://www.docker.com/blog/deploying-a-minecraft-docker-server-to-the-cloud/)" from [Guillaume Tardif](https://twitter.com/gtardif) (Senior Software Engineer @ Docker)

> The command to start this locally is now much simpler:
>
> ```
> $ docker-compose --project-name mc up
> ```
>
> And to deploy to ACI, still using the ACI context I created previously:
>
> ```
> $ docker compose --project-name mc2 up
> ```

See also "[How To Deploy Containers to Azure ACI using Docker CLI and Compose](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-containers-to-azure-aci-using-docker-cli-and-compose/)" from [Peter McKee](https://twitter.com/pmckee,) ([Coding Adventures.io](https://codingadventures.io/about/)).

You can easily create your ACI-complient context:

```
docker context create aci myaci
docker-compose push
docker context use myaci
docker compose up
```

Plus, "[VSCode Docker extension can now run containers in Azure Container Instances](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2020/07/22/vs-code-docker-extension-azure-containers-instances/)" from [Mike Morton](https://twitter.com/mikemorton_msft) (Senior Program Manager - Microsoft - Visual Studio)

[image: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/uploads/prod/sites/37/2020/07/CreateContextPlusActions.gif]

Comment: But ACI != AppService right?

Comment: @MolteNolte Yes, ACI is Azure Containers Instance (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/). So different from AppService (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/).