# Bicep scripting out for Azure web application running a container using docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I am currently running sonarqube using a container, my experience of containers is quite limited. However having done a lot of reading, here is where I am currently stuck.

I am running the docker compose commands below on an Azure web app, and so far the web app works and loads sonarqube, however there are some nuances with what I have running, but its not for this post.

**section 1**

```
version: '3.3'
   
services:
    sonarqube:
        image: sonarqube:10.0-developer
        command: "-Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false"
        ports:
         - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
          - sonarqube-conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
          - sonarqube-data:/opt/sonarqube/data
          - sonarqube-extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
          - sonarqube-bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
        environment:
          - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.windows.net:1433;databaseName=${SONAR_JDBC_DATABASE};user=[${SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME}]@[xxx];password=${SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
          - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=${SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME}
          - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD= ${SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD}
          - SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE=true
   

volumes:
    sonarqube-conf:
        external: true        
    sonarqube-data:
        external: true
    sonarqube-extensions:
        external: true
    sonarqube-bundled-plugins:
        external: true

    mssql:
```

**What am I trying to do ?**

Script out the manually created web application using Bicep.

**Web app module**

// modules/webApp.bicep

```
param appServicePlanIdParam string
param environmentParam string
param linuxFxVersionParam string
param webAppNameParam string

var webAppName = '${webAppNameParam}-${environmentParam}'
var location = resourceGroup().location

var configReferenceWindows = {
  metadata :[
    {
      name:'CURRENT_STACK'
      value:'dotnet'
    }
  ]
  netFrameworkVersion:'v4.0'
  appSettings: [
    {
      name: 'TenantId'
      value: subscription().tenantId
    }
  ]
}



resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  tags: {}
  properties: {
    metadata: [
      {
        name: 'Current_Stack'
        value: 'dotnet|4.0'
      }
      {
        name: 'alwaysOn'
        value: true
      }
    ]

    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
      ]
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersionParam
      alwaysOn: true          
    }
 
    serverFarmId: appServicePlanIdParam
    httpsOnly: true
  }
  identity:{
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }

}

output sysIdentity string = webApp.identity.principalId
```

Web App Configuration Module

```
// modules/webApp.bicep
param ConfigappServicePlanIdParam string
param ConfigenvironmentParam string
param ConfiglinuxFxVersionParam string
param ConfigwebAppNameParam string
param kvName string

var webAppName = '${ConfigwebAppNameParam}-${ConfigenvironmentParam}'
var location = resourceGroup().location


resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'app,linux,container'
  tags: {}
  properties: {
    metadata: [
      {
        name: 'Current_Stack'
        value: 'dotnet|4.0'
      }
      {
        name: 'alwaysOn'
        value: true
      }
    ]

    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD'
          value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${kvName};SecretName=database_password)'
        }
        {
          name: 'SONAR_JDBC_URL'
          value: 'jdbc:sqlserver://xx.database.windows.net;databaseName=xxx'
        }
        {
          name: 'SONAR_JDBC_DATABASE'
          value: 'db_name'
        }
        {
          name: 'SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME'
          value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${kvName};SecretName=database_username)'
        }
        {
          name: 'SONARQUBE_IMAGE'
          value: 'sonarqube:10.0-developer'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE'
          value: 'false'
        }
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL'
          value: 'https://index.docker.io/v1'
        }

  
      ]

      alwaysOn: true          
      numberOfWorkers: 1
      linuxFxVersion: 'COMPOSE|xx'

    }
 
    serverFarmId: ConfigappServicePlanIdParam
  }

}
```

Main.Bicep which calls the modules

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

param appServicePlan object
param webApp object
param resGroup object
param SharedresGroup object
param keyvault object
param appServicePlanOS string = 'linux'


var linuxOffer = 'linux'


module appPlan 'modules/appService/appServicePlan.bicep' = {
  scope: rg
  name: appServicePlan.name
  params: {
    appServicePlanNameParam: appServicePlan.name
    appServicePlanSkuParam: appServicePlan.sku
    environmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment
    os: appServicePlan.os
  }
}

module app 'modules/appService/webApp.bicep' = {
  scope: rg
  name: 'webAppConfig'
  params: {
    appServicePlanIdParam: appPlan.outputs.aspId
    environmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment
    linuxFxVersionParam: webApp.linuxFxVersion
    webAppNameParam: webApp.name
  }
}

module appConfig 'modules/appService/webAppConfiguration.bicep' = {
  scope: rg
  name: webApp.name
  params: {
    ConfigappServicePlanIdParam: appPlan.outputs.aspId
    ConfigenvironmentParam: resGroup.tags.Environment
    ConfiglinuxFxVersionParam: webApp.linuxFxVersion
    ConfigwebAppNameParam: webApp.name
    kvName: resourceKeyVaultModule.outputs.name
  }
  dependsOn: [
    app
  ]
}
```

**What is the issue**

When I look at the deployment output, this is what I see.
[image]

What I would like is the Docker compose option with the commands in section 1.

Lastly, it also begs the question. Is this the best way to achieve what I am trying to do, is it possible to build the container from the commands in section 1 and save this onto ACR ? Then the web app can simply reference a container on ACR ? Is this even possible and is there a guide that I can follow which will illustrate how to do this ?

I know some may ask, why not use ACI ? The reason I am not doing this is because using ACI means no https, and from the research I have done, I would need to use a reverse proxy. I am looking for a straight forward solution. I have come across this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303659/using-docker-compose-in-azure-app-service), I am not sure how relevant it is.